# MVVM framework for Xamarin.Forms

Tags: mvvm, xamarin.forms

Can someone explain What benefits an MVVM framework such as ReactiveUI or MVVM Light provides to Xamarin.Forms application? we can implement INotifyPropertyChanged in our viewmodels without using any of these frameworks.
Am I missing something?

Comment: If INotifyPropertyChanged is all you need, then there's for benefit to you. These Frameworks usually bring some nice tools like DI, auto loading/binding and more. They just make life a little easier.

Answer (score 2):

I'm an author of a small MVVM framework for Xamarin.Forms (https://github.com/daniel-luberda/DLToolkit.PageFactory). I'll try to point some advantages of using it as some of features are common for other frameworks too:

- Ready to use `INotifyPropertyChanged` implementation (just inherit from `BaseViewModel` or `BaseModel`)
- ViewModel oriented Navigation (you can move your navigation logic to view models)
- Built-in messaging to easily pass data/arguments between pages or view models
- Page caching and reusing (better UI experience as views/pages are reused)
- Every page has access to typed ViewModel instance which is automatically instantiated and wired to BindingContext

Those features vary between libraries. Some of more advanced MVVM frameworks offer you a possibility to move your entire project to a different platforms/sdks as they have multi platform support. It may be a nice deal for a larger projects.

Sample code to illustrate some features (the code is called from a ViewModel):

```
PageFactory.GetPageFromCache<SecondPageModel>()
    .ResetPageModel()
    .SendActionToPageModel((model) => { model.Message = "Hello World!"; })
    .PushPage();
```

Answer (score 1):

There is more to an MVVM Framework than just `INotifyPropertyChanged`. To give just a couple of examples there are:

- **RelayCommand** - A class that can provides an implementation of the `ICommand` interface and allows you to bind a delegate to the view. Useful for buttons
- **EventToCommand** - This allows you to bind an event to a command in your view model. Instead of having to use code behind for `UIElement Events`

These are just two classes that are provided by an MVVM Framework such as `MVVMLight`

By using MVVMLight it means that you do not have to implement `INotifyPropertyChanged` in every project you just make sure your `ViewModel` inherits from `ViewModelBase` and you also don't have to write your own implementation in every project for the two classes mentioned above.

The final thing to mention is that you can also install code snippets for `MVVMLight`. Meaning that writing code is EVEN faster!

For example if you would like a property that raises property changed as well just use the mvvmlight property snippet. And similarly if you would like a `RelayCommand` property you can just use the `mvvmlight RelayCommand` snippet

Answer (score 1):

The Model-View-ViewModel (MVVM) architectural pattern was invented with XAML in mind. The pattern enforces a separation of the XAML user interface (the View) from the underlying data (the Model) through a class that serves as an intermediary between the View and the Model (the ViewModel). The View and the ViewModel are often connected through data bindings defined in the XAML file. The BindingContext for the View is usually an instance of the ViewModel. [Please click here to see more details and sample code.](https://developer.xamarin.com/guides/xamarin-forms/user-interface/xaml-basics/data_bindings_to_mvvm/)

You don't need to use ReactiveUI or MVVM Light, you can just use INotifyPropertyChanged interface to notify clients that a property value has changed.Below, you can see my ViewModelBase class code, hope this helps you out;

```
public class ViewModelBase : INotifyPropertyChanged
{
    #region INotifyPropertyChanged
    public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;

    public void OnPropertyChanged([CallerMemberName] string propertyName = null)
    {
        if (PropertyChanged != null)
        {
            PropertyChanged(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(propertyName));
        }
    }
    #endregion
}
```

In my ViewModel here is how I inherit from ViewModelBase and how I create my property;

```
public class ImageButtonViewModel : ViewModelBase
{
 // ...
 private string header;
 public string Header
 {
      get
      {
          return header;
       }
      set
        {
          header = value;
          OnPropertyChanged();
         }
  }
// ...
}
```

Answer (score 1):

I have been using with great success with  [Askaiser.Mobile.Pillar](https://www.nuget.org/packages/Askaiser.Mobile.Pillar/), and I do not see anything wrong, I am still investigating, but this has become a great candidate for my projects.
[Doc](https://github.com/asimmon/Pillar)

I hope I have helped.

A greeting

Answer (score 1):

The plain truth is that MVVM Frameworks (and their IOC Containers) are short-cuts to save you time.  They come at an extraordinary expense:

They cause a simplistic alignment between views, view models and models. Only one can really belong to another.  This is not "IOC" -- it's a hard-coded assignment  based on a file naming convention such as this:

> MainPage
>
> MainViewModel
>
> MainModel

In a real injection scenario, any number of models could serve any number of view models, provided they implement the proper interface.  Also, any number of view models can serve any number of views as long as those view models support the views' interface(s).

MVVM Frameworks create classes through a reflection trick using a string prefix. In the example earlier, the string "Main" allows us to find the page, the view model and the model. But this is *not* view-model-to-view-model navigation. It is ***string to view model navigation***.

The frameworks create classes using Activator.CreateInstance, which creates havoc on the compile-time linker.

The frameworks instantiate using hyper-simplistic constructor parameter logic.  Modern programs use instantiation as a form of control. In these frameworks, there is no real control.

The complete code for these remarks is at https://github.com/marcusts/xamarin-forms-annoyances.  See the solution called MvvmAntipattern.sln.

The GitHub site also provides links to a more detailed discussion on this topic.